# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in()

Tags: php, wordpress

quisiera que me pudieran ayudar con el siguiente problema, me aparece el error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in(), ya busqué en muchos foros pero aún no encuentro la respuesta.

archivo a.php

```
function resultado(){
if (is_user_logged_in()){
        $cu = wp_get_current_user();
        $reg = "SELECT registro FROM wp_users where ID=".$cu->ID;
}
}
```

archivo b.php

```
if(isset($_GET['lin'])){
        $xx = $_GET['lin'];
        salir($xx);
    }
    function salir($xxx){
        if(is_user_logged_in()){
            echo 'loge';
        }
    }
```

si quito la función ¨if(is_user_logged_in())¨ funciona bien. mi pregunta principal es por qué me funciona en el archivo a.php y no me funciona en el b.php? Estoy trabajando con WordPress y ambos archivos (a.php y b.php) estan incluidos en el archivo functions.php

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes la función  is_user_logged_in()? Se está "quejando" de que no la encuentra.

Comment: No entiendo bien cómo lo tienes organizado. Dices que que si quitas la función funciona en el archivo a.php pero no en el b.php. Pero al mismo tiemo dices que tiees esos archivos en el archivo functions.php....
No tiene mucho sentido lo que dices

Comment: Explica mejor tu contexto. ¿Cómo se relacionan los archivos a y b? ¿Estás trabajando con un plugin o algo? ¿Estás trabajando con `add_action` para agregar las funciones? etc.